# Where can I find documentation/specification for mining pool communication?

Tags: protocol, miner, documentation

I am looking for documentation or specification of communication/protocol between client and pool. Is there some or do I have to dig into source code of geth?

(Yes, I know about the RPC documentation, I am looking for something that describes what data are transmitter, how does miner initiate communication with pool, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest place I know of is to look into the source code of [sammy007/open-ethereum-pool](https://github.com/sammy007/open-ethereum-pool).

Here are the main JSON-RPC methods you will need to support, from [sammy007/open-ethereum-pool/proxy/proxy.go, lines 232-269](https://github.com/sammy007/open-ethereum-pool/blob/master/proxy/proxy.go#L232-L269):

```
switch req.Method {
    case "eth_getWork":
        reply, errReply := s.handleGetWorkRPC(cs)
        if errReply != nil {
            cs.sendError(req.Id, errReply)
            break
        }
        cs.sendResult(req.Id, &reply)
    case "eth_submitWork":
        if req.Params != nil {
            var params []string
            err := json.Unmarshal(*req.Params, &params)
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf("Unable to parse params from %v", cs.ip)
                s.policy.ApplyMalformedPolicy(cs.ip)
                break
            }
            reply, errReply := s.handleSubmitRPC(cs, login, vars["id"], params)
            if errReply != nil {
                err = cs.sendError(req.Id, errReply)
                break
            }
            cs.sendResult(req.Id, &reply)
        } else {
            s.policy.ApplyMalformedPolicy(cs.ip)
            errReply := &ErrorReply{Code: -1, Message: "Malformed request"}
            cs.sendError(req.Id, errReply)
        }
    case "eth_getBlockByNumber":
        reply := s.handleGetBlockByNumberRPC()
        cs.sendResult(req.Id, reply)
    case "eth_submitHashrate":
        cs.sendResult(req.Id, true)
    default:
        errReply := s.handleUnknownRPC(cs, req.Method)
        cs.sendError(req.Id, errReply)
    }
}
```

And the easiest way to work out what data is transmitted is to compile it, insert debug statements and view the data being transmitted.

You may also want to look at [sammy007/ether-proxy](https://github.com/sammy007/ether-proxy), a simpler version of sammy007's pool mining software.

---

**EDIT 17/06/2016 - Adding links to the JSON-RPC calls for completeness**

Here is the documentation for the JSON-RPC calls required:

- [eth_getWork](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getwork)
- [eth_submitWork](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_submitwork)
- [eth_submitHashrate](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_submithashrate)

Comment: Thanks, I knew about these projects but I was hoping there was some kind of documentation.